# Вставить датафрейм со столбцом с датами библиотекой clickhouse-driver

Tags: python, pandas, clickhouse

Создал таблицу:

```
create table t
(
    order_date     Date
)
engine = ReplacingMergeTree()
PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(order_date)
ORDER BY order_date
SAMPLE BY order_date
SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192;
```

Хочу вставить в нее датафрейм:

```
pd.DataFrame([[datetime.date(2020, 12, 21)]])
```

Вставку пытаюсь осуществить [методом insert_dataframe](https://clickhouse-driver.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=dataframe#clickhouse_driver.Client.insert_dataframe)

Клиент:

```
from clickhouse_driver import Client

client = Client('localhost', settings={'use_numpy': True})
```

Вставка:

```
client.insert_dataframe(f'INSERT INTO t VALUES', df)
```

Если пытаюсь вставить `df = pd.DataFrame([[datetime.date(2020, 12, 21)]])`, то получаю ошибку:

```
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'datetime.date'
```

Если пытаюсь вставить `df = pd.DataFrame([['2020-12-21']])`, то получаю ошибку:

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2020-12-21'
```

Если `df = pd.DataFrame([[1608560160]])` (текущий unixtimestamp), то вставка происходит, но дата - 2092-01-17.

Как вставить столбец с датой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно передать дату, как число дней от [1970-01-01](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/data-types/datetime/):

```py
from datetime import date
import pandas
from clickhouse_driver import Client

EPOCH_START = date(1970, 1, 1)


def get_count_days(dt: date) -> int:
    return (dt - EPOCH_START).days


client = Client('localhost', settings={'use_numpy': True})

df = pandas.DataFrame([{'order_date': get_count_days(date(2020, 12, 26))}])
client.insert_dataframe(f'INSERT INTO t VALUES', df)
```